# Extend the stack size on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, stack-size

When I try to extend the stack size on macOS Sierra using the command `ulimit -s unlimited` the terminal print the next message:

> -bash: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted.

I also tried to use `sudo ulimit -s unlimited` but it doesn't leave me either. Anyone know something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a hard limit for the stack size on OS X that can be seen running:

```
ulimit -Hs
```

This is the maximum you can set the stack size as. So instead of unlimited the best you can do is

```
ulimit -s 65532
```

See [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245019/how-to-change-the-stack-size-using-ulimit-or-per-process-on-mac-os-x-for-a-c-or).